# How to Stop Sublist from Inheriting Parent List Parameters

Tags: lists

So I'm using the following user-defined list:

```
\newenvironment{topiclist}{%
    \normalsize 
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.1in}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{.2in}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5in}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bigskipamount}}}
    {\end{list}}
```

When I now use itemize inside topiclist, it inherits these parameters.  How do I prevent that?

Comment: Why don't you use a custom description environmeny with package `enumitem`? Yjis package makes customisation particularly easy, through a system of key-values.

Answer (score 1):

- Based on [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908)'s comment.
- Using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.

---

```
% Inspired by https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\myRandomtext}{This is a test text. This is a test text. This is a test text. This is a test text.}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[
    labelwidth = 20mm,
    labelsep = 10mm,
    leftmargin = 30mm,
    itemsep = 5mm,
    ]
\item[Label] \myRandomtext
   \begin{itemize}
      \item \myRandomtext
        \begin{itemize}
        \item \myRandomtext
        \end{itemize}
   \item \myRandomtext
   \end{itemize}
\item[Label] \myRandomtext
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

*(Taken from the manual.)*

Maybe relevant:

[image]

*(Taken from the manual.)*

Comment: I like the recommendation to use `enumitem`, but your example seems to illustrate my point. Your `itemize` doesn't look right.  The bullets are not properly indented relative to the previous `description` item, and the label separation is overly large.  Please inform me if I'm not seeing this correctly.

Comment: I did just enter random numbers into the example so don't take the output as proof for anything.

Comment: Take the code as a starting point for your own research.